# JClouds minDisk option usage

Tags: jclouds

When creating an instance via TemplateBuilder, setting some value in .minDisk(sizeInGigs) has no effect on the utimate size of the device created; the size is determined by the size of the device on the image utilized to create the instance.

For instance, at AWS EC2 choosing an image (AMI) id of 'us-west-1/ami-0c6269b2ddb61bb2e' will result in an instance with a boot device of 30G after the instance is created.

Is there a mechanism in the API to have the boot device reflect the size specified in .minDisk()?  Or is there some other provider (e.g., EC2) specific option that can be set to have that boot device sized to some specified value.